# What are the units for Sum & SampleCount stats for ReadProvisionedThroughputExceeded metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, throughput

What does it mean to have different values for `Sum()` vs `SampleCount()` stats over `ReadProvisonedThroughputExceeded` metric for kinesis stream? Shouldn't it be the same?

Period = 5 mins

[image: SampleCount]

[image: Sum]

Answer (score 1):

The `ReadProvisonedThroughputExceeded` shows the

> The number of `GetRecords` calls throttled

See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html).

Meric is published per `GetRecords` call and the value is 0 if the call was not throttled or 1 if the call was throttled. So graphing the **SampleCount** will give you the number of `GetRecords` calls. **Sum** will give you the total number of throttled calls. The most useful stat here is probably the **Average**, which will give you the percentage of throttled calls.